# Switch from NVidia to internal Intel HD graphics - OpenGL does not work

Tags: intel-graphics, opengl

I switched today to the internal Intel HD graphics of my G630T CPU. The desktop works but XBMC would not start. It complains that it needs OpenGL accelerated hardware.

When I check the System Info - Graphics, there is only a generic(?) card listed:

`Driver` (with the space in the beginning)

`Experience Standard`

then I checked

```
lshw -C video
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:42 memory:fb800000-fbbfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:ff00(size=64)
```

I am not sure if here is everything correct but it seems not completely wrong to me. However, glxinfo is definitively strange:

```
glxinfo 
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 `3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP` and help is very much appreciated, as I have no clue what I could do (beginner in Linux).

Martur

Comment: Have you removed your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file after removing the nVidia card?

Comment: No, should I do that?
There is not much in this file:
    Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Device"
    Option "NoLogo" "True"
    EndSection

Comment: I renamed the file (instead of deleting it) and did a restert but that did not make any difference.

Comment: You did not remove the nVidia driver did you?

Comment: No, at first I just activated the internal graphics and plugged the monitor to it. Then the NVidia drivers were still listed in the "System Settings - Additional Drivers" menu. Thereafter I removed the NVidia card from the computer and the drivers were not listed any longer.

Comment: You still need to remove them! :)

Comment: How do I do that in the right way without messing things up?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to remove the nvidia drivers so that the driver does not try to get itself loaded instead of your Intel card.

Normally no further installation of drivers is required for the Intel built in driver but if the nVidia driver is getting loaded it will take over.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I removed the NVidia card and it is not available any longer. This is not a laptop.

Comment: Edited to remove the nVidia driver and force reinstall of X.

Comment: This solution helped me on Lenovo t410 (with intel i915 only). Thanks!

Comment: Massive thanks. Worked on `Asus A53S`  - `Intel Core i5` w/ `Nvidia GEFORCE GT540M`

Comment: WOW-I gave up after my last post and did not see you corrected your answer. I reinstalled the Nvidia gfx. However, today, with 12.04 LTS I had the exact same trouble and found my original post by mistake. This solution worked now. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't have to reinstall X or rm xorg.conf -- all I had to do was purge Nvidia.

Comment: This seems to be kind of an essential step for new distributions of Ubuntu, when installed on a system with only Intel onboard graphics. I never had nVidia anything on my laptop, and 13.10 was booting super slow because of all the nVidia drivers. Now it is quite fast in addition to the problem being solved! Thanks!

Comment: Worked on Sony Vaio S SVS1511AGXB with Ubuntu 13.10. The screen was going black after log-in (lack of acceleration -> compiz wasn't running -> gnome/unity were not being launched, but could be started from a terminal). Bumblebee also did not help.

This saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. A global answer about **how to switch driver from one to another**. This answer helps a thread in Ubuntu Forums to be solved: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234888. Thank you.

Comment: This fixed my compiz problem. Recently, I had a full-upgrade (Debian), and compiz won't show window border. After an investigation, I found that GLX is missing. Well, after purged nvidia* packages and reboot, everything happy again. +1