# broken gnome shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes

After some updates my gnome-shell theme is broken (looks like old gnome2).

I tried many things:

- uinstalled alls gnome-shell extensions
- uninstalled and again installed gnome-shell as well
- uinstalled gnome-tweak-tool
- removed ~/.themes directory
- removed ~/.config/dconf
- installed lxappearance
- removed gnome-accessibility-themes and then installed gnome-themes-standard

Nothing helped and right now I'm loosing my mind

Some info:

System Info -> Graphics shows: "Experience Fallback"

```
gnome-shell --replace
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

(gnome-shell:7853): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: The OpenGL version could not be determined
Window manager error: Unable to initialize Clutter.
```

Other command

```
gnome-shell
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

(gnome-shell:7855): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: The OpenGL version could not be determined
Window manager error: Unable to initialize Clutter.
```

Comment: Looks like a nasty bug. What video card are you using and which drivers ?

Comment: I have Intel GMA X3100 in my thinkpad t61. I have default drivers and haven't changed anything. Previously everything was ok any even /etc/lib/nux/unit_support_test -p got possitive results. Right now looks like there is some driver problem. I tried purging and reinstalling xserver-xorg as well

Answer (score 5):

It looks like one package installed nvidia drivers even though I only have intel graphics. I removed it and followed the following topic and it finally worked for me

[Switch from NVidia to internal Intel HD graphics - OpenGL does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86465/switch-from-nvidia-to-internal-intel-hd-graphics-opengl-does-not-work)