# How do I change my desktop theme from grey bars to black bars?

Tags: themes, appearance, ambiance, radiance

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 and I have just installed the official Nvidia driver. now every time I log in, any gnome based desktop replacement (like unity or cinnamon) doesn't start correctly. It displays the ugly gray bars. Cinnamon looks like this: [image: desktop]
Unity looks like this: [image: unity]

Is there a way to reset the gnome settings or what else can I do? I have tried to uninstall and reinstall cinnamon, but the problem is still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: OpenGl did not work correctly. So i found the soulution here: [Switch from NVidia to internal Intel HD graphics - OpenGL does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86465/switch-from-nvidia-to-internal-intel-hd-graphics-opengl-does-not-work)

I had to reinstall xorg / xserver ...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop --> `Change Desktop Background` --> `Theme` --> `Ambiance`. The white panel comes with the Radiance theme.

[image]