# How to install OpenCV without nVidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, opencv

I have a laptop with on-board Intel graphics. I have been using OpenCV for years with this machine and I have managed to avoid manual compilation so far. But in Ubuntu 13.10, when I try to install `libopencv-dev` from the repositories, it brings along `libopencv-ocl`, which seems to be dependent on nvidia drivers. Letting the driver install messes up my xserver completely and when I do `glxinfo` afterwards, I get this:

```
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

To solve this, I purge all nVidia drivers and reinstall xserver, much like it has been suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/86467/59061), and when I purge the nvidia drivers, OpenCV development libraries are also removed, as `apt-get` tells me they are `no longer needed`. This is foreign to me, because I expected a warning that I have installed packages that depend on this, but how can removing a dependency automatically remove the package I installed without warnings or asking? I understand it has something to do with nVidia being the provider of the `libopencv-ocl` in the repo. How could I get around it? I would rather not compile OpenCV if I can help it. I have seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19591807), but not a suitable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, to get around it you can install an alternative provider of libopencl1.  If there isn't one available for your specific graphics card (i.e. one for AMD/ATI appears to be absent from the repositories) you can use the generic one:

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

If you already installed libopencv-dev, you will also want to remove the redundant packages it brought in:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Seems strange to me that the Nvidia provider is brought in by default rather than the generic one - maybe some packaging wizard can sort this out.

There is a bug for this issue here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opencv/+bug/1245260

Comment: I ended up compiling OpenCV 2.4.6 in the meantime, but this answer is sure to help many. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-highgui-dev
```

then compile from source, this also has a benefit that the nonfree moudle of SIFT and SURF is available.